Is my proof valid for Exercise 7.3 of book "Introduction to Lie Algebras" by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon
Exercise 7.3 of book "Introduction to Lie Algebras" by Karin and Mark: Show that $V$ is irreducible if and only if for any non-zero $v \in V$ the submodule generated by $v$ contains all elements of $V$. The submodule generated by $v$ is defined to be the subspace of $V$ spanned by all elements of the form $x1 \cdot (x2 \cdot ... \cdot (x_m \cdot v)...)$, where $x_1,...,x_m \in L$.
I think I know the answer to this one, but am not very certain, especially on the "if direction". I don't feel good about it, because I am only using the prerequisite as an argument to contradict. I seems to see more of using the opposite final claim as the contradiction...
Would to love to hear about feedback / corrections / suggestions, thanks!
My proof:

the only-if direction: because $V$ irreducible, its submodules can either be $\{0\}$ or $V$. Thus resulting submodule has to have the same dimension as $V$, which means that it contains all elements.
the if direction: Given that the submodule contains all elements, let's assume that V is reducible. Then there $\exists W \subseteq V$, such that $\forall x \in L$, and $\forall w \in W$, we have $x \cdot w \in W$. However, $x1 \cdot (x2 \cdot ... \cdot (x_m \cdot w)...) \in W$ cannot contain all elements in V unless $W = V$, and this conflicts the prerequisite.    $\space\space\space\space\square$

This is not for assignment, just reading

Your basic idea is ok. A detail not to be forgotten is in the sentence "The submodule generated by v is defined to be the subspace of V spanned by all elements of the form..."

In other words, the elements of the generated submodule are linear combinations of vectors of that form. I am  also willing to bet that (for most authors, don't know about yours) the definition of a submodule generated by a vector $v$  (or a collection $S$ of vectors) is simply the smallest submodule $M$ containing $v$ (or $S$). And a consequence ($\approx$ Lemma) of this is the description of $M$ as the set of linear combinations of $x_1\cdot(\cdots(x_m\cdot v)$, $m\ge0$ ($v\in S$).
